# AppSDK2 Stories By Iteration App not Displaying All Stories in the Iteration

Tags: rally

I wrote an app that builds a grid of User Stories filtered by Iteration. It seems to work, and there are no errors but the list of Stories is incomplete. Some Iterations have half of the stories missing in the grid. All Stories are in the same Project. What am I doing wrong? If you have suggestions on how to improve the code below please let me know. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>StoriesByIteration</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Rally.onReady(function () {
                    Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                        extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
                        componentCls: 'app',
                        scopeType: 'iteration',
                        comboboxConfig: {
                            labelWidth: 100,
                            width: 300
                        },

                        addContent: function() {
                            this._makeStore();
                        },

                        onScopeChange: function() {
                            this._makeStore();
                        },

                         _makeStore: function(){
                             Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                                model: 'UserStory',
                                fetch: ['FormattedID','Name'],
                                autoLoad: true,
                                filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
                                listeners: {
                                    load: this._onDataLoaded,
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            }); 
                        },

                        _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                            var stories = [];
                            Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                                var s  = {
                                    FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                                    Name: story.get('Name'),
                                };
                                this._createGrid(stories);
                                stories.push(s);
                            }, this);
                        },             

                        _createGrid: function(stories) {
                            var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                                data: stories,
                                pageSize: 100,  
                            });

                            if (!this.grid) {
                                this.grid = this.add({
                                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                                    store: myStore,
                                    columnCfgs: [
                                        {
                                           text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                                            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
                            } else {
                            this.grid.reconfigure(myStore);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                        name:"StoriesByIteration",
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
                .app { }
            </style>
        </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move

```
this._createGrid(stories);
```

outside of the loop:

```
 _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                var stories = [];
                Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                            var s  = {
                                FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: story.get('Name'),
                            };
                            stories.push(s);
                }, this);
                this._createGrid(stories);
    },
```